# DAX to Calculate the Users in Current month not in Previous month and finally get the count for every calendar month with the Filters

Tags: dax

How can I do this in DAX ?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT  DISTINCT user_id64
FROM 
`fact_revenue_users_daily`
WHERE `Is_Paid` = 1
AND shard_id = 9
AND `Date_Payment`>='2023-01-01' 
AND `Date_Payment`<'2023-02-01' 
EXCEPT 
SELECT  DISTINCT user_id64
FROM 
`fact_revenue_users_daily`
WHERE  `Is_Paid` = 1
AND shard_id = 9
AND `Date_Payment`>='2023-02-01' 
AND `Date_Payment`<'2023-03-01' 
)A
```

tried this did not get correct results

```
CountUsersInCurrentNotInPrevious = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(
        EXCEPT(
            CALCULATETABLE(
                VALUES('Subscription Revenue Data'[User_Id64]),
                'Subscription Revenue Data'[Is_Paid] = 1,
                USERELATIONSHIP('Subscription Revenue Data'[Date_Payment], 'DimDatePayment'[Date Payment])
            ),
            CALCULATETABLE(
                VALUES('Subscription Revenue Data'[User_Id64]),
                'DimDatePayment'[Date Payment] = EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1),
                'Subscription Revenue Data'[Is_Paid] = 1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Why does the first have `USERELATIONSHIP` and the second one not? What is `'DimDatePayment'`? Is it a Date table and is this being used for your month filter? Can you update your question with a snip of your data model so we can see the relationship between the two tables.